# bootstrap using google graph error: this.q.Ee is not a function in

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-visualization

How to solve this error
**Error:** for this.q.Ee is not a function when more then one google char using

There is my bundles

```
</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('number', 'X');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Water Usage');
            data.addRows([
                [1, 23],   [1, 10],  [2, 23],
                [3, 17],  [4, 18],  [5, 9],
                [6, 11],  [7, 27],  [8, 33],[9, 10],[10, 80],[11, 20],
                [18, 52], [19, 54], [20, 42],
                [21, 55], [22, 56], [23, 57],[25,0],[27,0],
                [30, 80]
            ]);

            var options = {
                width: 600,
                height: 150,
                    hAxis: {
                    title: 'Days'
                    },
                    vAxis: {
                    title: 'Water Details'
                    }
                };
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('ex012'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
    }


    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["bar"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Month','Usage'],
          ['Jan','20'],
          ['Feb','45'],
          ['Mar','80'],
        ]);



        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart1'));

        chart.draw(data);
      }
    </script>
```

And how to change google api chart sizes for user wish, how to implement single bar chart and that bar will showed on ther different color

Answer (score 0):

Just change that  `google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["bar"]});` to `google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["bar"]});` to